# Change the Font Size of pairs_text in pairs plot (base R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpairs

I am using pairs to plot mosaic plots of various variables in the SleepStudy dataset.

```
SleepStudy_factors <- SleepStudy[sapply(SleepStudy, is.factor)] 
SleepStudy_factors <- table(SleepStudy_factors)


pairs(SleepStudy_factors, diag_panel = pairs_text,highlighting = 2,direction=c("v","h"))
```

With this, I get a pairs plot where the diagonal entries are the names of the variables and the different levels they have.

[image: Pairs Plot]

I am trying to decrease the font size of the text in the diagonal boxes , I have tried cex with text.panel but that is not making any difference.

```
pairs(SleepStudy_factors, diag_panel = pairs_text,highlighting = 2,direction=c("v","h") ,text_panel=list(cex=0.5))
```

Need some tips to decrease the text font?

Answer (score 0):

If I remembered right, you should change the parameter `cex.labels`.

Also you can change a style of text by `font.labels`

And try to cut/write text in multiple lines. It will look better.